# Eslint rule "padding-line-between-statements" not working as expected

Tags: javascript, eslint

I am trying to configure eslint to force newlines after return statements and block openings using the padding-line-between-statements rule. 
Enforcing a newline before the return works well but I can't get it after by just swapping prev/next.

Here is what I tried in eslintrc.js

```
"padding-line-between-statements": [ "warn",
        { blankLine: "always", prev: "return", next: "*" }
]
```

What am I missing? Shouldn't it work like this as described in [documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/padding-line-between-statements)? 
Or is there a better rule for wrapping block content in new lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `padding-line-between-statements` rule works adding a padding line between two statements. As there is no statement after the return it won't never work. 
The wildcard `*` means "any statements", but that doesn't mean *anything*. There is a list of valid statement types in the [docs](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/padding-line-between-statements).

Anyways, check out the [Google JavaScript Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html#formatting-vertical-whitespace):

> [A single blank line appears] within method bodies, sparingly to create logical groupings of statements. Blank lines at the start or end of a function body are not allowed.

Of course it's just a style guide, but I thought it's interesting to have in mind that Google considers that a bad practice style-wise.